# SYnaptics wants to redownload already downloaded deb packages

Tags: software-installation, deb, synaptic, offline

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop from scratch. Now, after installing system, I wanted to update the system as well as install other applications which I use.
So, I did an sudo apt-get update an then installed Synaptic.
Thereafter, I marked all upgrades and made a download script through Synaptic. Next, I searched and marked all the applications I want to install and generated other download script.

Next, I went to my brother's system having high speed net connectivity and downloaded applications as per both scripts, totaling 1619 deb files of around 900 MBs. Then, I took this whole deb file folder to my laptop and tried to install them through Synaptic [files>add downloaded packages].
But, Synaptic, showed it still needs to download ~65 MB of files. So, I proceeded with the install and then canceled as soon as it started downloading files. So, it showed a windows, stating which files it wanted to download. When, I inspected the files, I found that I already have those packages, though I have 64 bit version, and Synaptic wanted 32 bit. I however still copied them in a txt file and downloaded them again via my another PC. Came back, made a consolidated folder and retried to install them through Synaptic.

Now, it again showed it wants to download around ~66 MB of files. So, I repeated the above stated process to find out which files do it still needs. This time, I noticed that it wants to download files, which are already downloaded and are in that consolidated folder.

I cleared apt-cache, but still the same result. I moved those 'problematic' deb files to another folder and this time tried to install them only specifically, but synaptic just seems not to see anything in that folder.

So, my questions are:

1. Why is this happening and how to resolve it? Why it want to download those files, when they are already downloaded.
2. Why do Ubuntu install some 32 bit versions on a 64 bit machine, even when 64 bit versions' deb are available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and the only way to resolve it was to use dpkg. Thus, all packages that were already downloaded were installed and Ubuntu did not ask to download them again. I hope it helps you.

With regard to the 32-bit libraries, Ubuntu installs to ensure compatibility with other programs or processes that may need them. I also think it's a waste of space, but anyway...